# Prometheus metrics for response time and number of requests

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks, promql

I have Prometheus and Grafana deployed in my Kubernetes cluster. I also have several applications running in the form of Deployment.

There is a Deployment named `router-api`, which is exposed to public in the form of URL via Ingress (e.g., https://router-api.mydomain.org)

There is another Deployment called `my-api`, which receives requests from `router-api` and manages the requests.

The `router-api` sends requests to `my-api` using `my-api`'s Service name, i.e., `http://my-api-svc.my-api.svc.cluster.local:1234/mycustompath`.

Unlike `router-api`, `my-api` is not exposed to public.

I want to query (and draw graphs whose x-axis is time) the followings using Prometheus and Grafana:

1. Number of requests on `router-api` and `my-api`
2. Average response time per request on `router-api` and `my-api`

I've Googled through it and found that `http_request_duration_seconds_sum` and `http_request_duration_seconds_count` may help, but those metrics seem to be missing in my environment.

I've deployed Prometheus using Prometheus Community Helm Chart with the version of 2.44.0.

Here are all the metrics I can find when I search using `request_duration_seconds_sum`.

```
apiserver_delegated_authn_request_duration_seconds_sum
apiserver_delegated_authz_request_duration_seconds_sum
apiserver_request_duration_seconds_sum
authentication_token_cache_request_duration_seconds_sum
cloudprovider_aws_api_request_duration_seconds_sum
coredns_dns_request_duration_seconds_sum
coredns_forward_request_duration_seconds_sum
coredns_health_request_duration_seconds_sum
etcd_request_duration_seconds_sum
field_validation_request_duration_seconds_sum
prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds_sum
prometheus_sd_kubernetes_http_request_duration_seconds_sum
rest_client_request_duration_seconds_sum
```

Which metric among them should I use for my purpose? Or, should I use anything other than above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What web server/framework are you using for your router and my apis?

Comment: @JeremyCowan They are both built with FastAPI.

Comment: 2 things. First, you need to make sure that your app is emitting metrics. By default, Prometheus scrapes metrics on port 9090 at /metrics. Second, verify that Prometheus is configured to scrape metrics from your router and api pods.

Comment: @JeremyCowan Do you know which metrics my app should emit and how it can be implemented given that the app is written in FastAPI?

Comment: You can use https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator/.